# Angular - Prevent HTTP request to be redirected to HTTPS

Tags: angular

I have an Angular App on an https server, and i want to make a request to an http server. But when i do the request the network automatically modify my request from http://xxx to https://xxx.

I tried adding this '< meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests >"' to the index.html but it's not working.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It probably is not the network, but your browser or the server that is changing the request to protect your information on the network.  You said you are on an https server.  Change to a http server.